# Parsing JavaScript regex with ANTLR

Tags: javascript, antlr

I have an ANTLR JavaScript grammar (taken from the Internet), which seem to support everything except for regex literals.

The problem with a regex literal is that you have two rules, essentially:

```
multiplicativeExpression
    : unaryExpression (LT!* ('*' | '/' | '%')^ LT!* unaryExpression)*
```

and

```
regexLiteral
    : '/' RegexLiteralChar* '/'
```

where the rule RegexLiteralChar uses different lexer rules than a normal expression (eg. a double quote does not terminate it).

This means that I need to, in some way, change some kind of lexer state from my parser. How can I do this? Is it even possible?

Comment: Communication between parser and lexer rules is not possible. Perhaps have a look at this grammar, which seem to handle regex-literals: http://research.xebic.com/es3/ (check the ZIP file).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the grammar mentioned in the comment by Bart Kiers [here](http://research.xebic.com/es3/), you can see this comment,

> The major challenges faced in defining this grammar were:
>
> -1- Ambiguity surrounding the DIV sign in relation to the multiplicative expression and the regular expression literal. This is
>   solved with some lexer driven magic: a gated semantical predicate
>   turns the recognition of regular expressions on or off, based on the
>   value of the RegularExpressionsEnabled property. When regular
>   expressions are enabled they take precedence over division
>   expressions. The decision whether regular expressions are enabled is
>   based on the heuristics that the previous token can be considered as
>   last token of a left-hand-side operand of a division.
>
> ...

The areRegularExpressionsEnabled() function is defined as,

```
private final boolean areRegularExpressionsEnabled()
{
    if (last == null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    switch (last.getType())
    {
    // identifier
        case Identifier:
    // literals
        case NULL:
        case TRUE:
        case FALSE:
        case THIS:
        case OctalIntegerLiteral:
        case DecimalLiteral:
        case HexIntegerLiteral:
        case StringLiteral:
    // member access ending 
        case RBRACK:
    // function call or nested expression ending
        case RPAREN:
            return false;
    // otherwise OK
        default:
            return true;
    }
}
```

And then the function is used in the RegularExpressionLiteral expression,

```
RegularExpressionLiteral
    : { areRegularExpressionsEnabled() }?=> DIV RegularExpressionFirstChar RegularExpressionChar* DIV IdentifierPart*
    ;
```